# Why does the Keep Forever option default to On in Google Drive?

Tags: google-drive

Last I checked Google Drive deleted older versions of the same file automatically [unless the **Keep Forever** option was turned on for the file](https://gizmodo.com/keep-older-versions-of-your-documents-on-google-drive-f-1671188573#:%7E:text=To%20keep%20a%20version%20forever,and%20manually%20add%20new%20ones.).  That's sensible, so old versions do not fill your GDrive.

Recently the Keep Forever option is On for me when I upload a new version of the same file, so I have to manually uncheck it every time.

Is this a bug or did google change the policy to keep all old files by default?

Answer (score -1):

Considering that there's no way to have the Keep Forever option default to off, it seems obvious that Google prefer users to use up their drive space sooner, so that they can make more money sooner.

Comment: We are not looking for kind of answers. "How" and "why" should focus on solving a problem about using a Web application, in this case, Google Drive, not guessing company motivations / ethics.